# ¿Son iguales class y typename en el contexto de template?

Tags: c++

Yo uso:

```
template<class T>
Arbol<T>::Arbol(){

}
```

cuando `T` va hacer una clase.

y uso:

```
template<typename T>
Arbol<T>::Arbol(){

}
```

cuando va `T` a ser un tipo por ejemplo `bool`, `char` osea tipos fundamentales.

Pero mirando un fragmento de código de un programa (no creado por mi) vi que usaba `typename` donde yo suelo usar `class`, y hasta ahora no me había fijado en eso. *si ahora me preguntas el por que, pues no sabría decir cien por cien el por que, pero quizás de alguna manera me (imagine) que el compilador diferenciaba cuando era un tipo incluido en el lenguaje y actuaba en consecuencia.*

Mi pregunta es:

¿Es igual utilizar uno u otro?

Pues los dos ahora lo he testado y trabajan bien pero no se, si se me esta escapando algo, o quizás exista alguna sutil diferencia entre `class` y `typename` en este contexto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En este contexto, ***Es lo mismo***, no hay ninguna diferencia.

Se pueden usar indistintamente y existen por motivos históricos.

En este [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304071611/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/08/11/212768.aspx) de Stan Lippman, explica que [Stroustrup](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) inicialmente no se quiso introducir un nuevo *keyword* y reutilizo `class`. Hasta el estandar ISO-C++ fue la única forma de declararlo.

Durante el proceso de estadarizacion, se descubrió que esto provocaba ambigüedades sintácticas (ver en el blog) y se decidió introducir un nuevo *keyword* para resolverlo. esto es `typename`. Finalmente se sobrecargo `class` para que funcione como `typename` y así mantener la compatibilidad hacia atrás.

Comment: por lo que entiendo entonces en algun momento en la historia aveces el usar class causaba errores por eso se creo typename

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo las ambigüedades se dan en otras partes del lenguaje y se introdujo `typename` para resolverlas. Alguien decidió de paso que era buena idea pormitir su uso en parámetros de plantilla en lugar de `class`.

Answer (score 9):

Respecto al uso de `typename` o `class` para declarar el parámetro-tipo de una plantilla, en la mayoría de casos usar una u otra de las palabras clave es indiferente, pero existen ciertos casos en que se requiere usar uno u otro.

Por ejemplo, **es obligatorio** usar `class` para el tipo de un parámetro-plantilla ([pero esto podría cambiar en C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html)) y es necesario usar `typename` para ayudar al compilador a distinguir entre un tipo o un valor (cuando el tipo es dependiente).

Extracto del Paper n4051 (la traducción es mía):

> #### Permitir typename en un parámetro-plantilla (template template)
>
> Desde la introducción de los alias de plantilla, C++ ha tenido plantillas que no son clases plantilla, en particular ahora tiene parámetros-plantilla que no son clases plantilla. Aún así, la sintaxis para los parámetros-plantilla aún requiere la palabra clave `class`:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> struct A {};
> template<typename T> using B = int;
>
> template<template<typename> class X> struct C;
> C<A> ca; // bien
> C<B> cb; // bien, no es una clase plantilla
> template<template<typename> typename X> struct D; // error, no se puede usar typename aqui
> ```

En resumen, para la gran mayoría de casos `class` o `typename` es indiferente, pero `typename` es la única opción para desambiguar tipos dependientes y `class` es obligatorio para el tipo de parámetro-plantilla; son los dos únicos casos en que ambas palabras clave no son intercambiables, pero no son los usos más comunes.

Answer (score 4):

A la hora de declarar un `template` sencillo es indiferente utilizar `class` o `typename`. Ambas son exactamente idénticas. Sin embargo, para determinados usos no tendremos tanta libertad de elección.

Si necesitamos hacer uso de un tipo proporcionado por la clase/estructura utilizada para especializar el `template` tendremos que redeclarar el tipo en nuestro `template`. En este caso tendremos que usar obligatoriamente `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    typedef typename T::type newType;
};

template<class T>
class Foo
{
    typedef typename T::type newType;
};
```

Si uno de los tipos del `template` resulta ser otro `template` (por ejemplo un contenedor) tendremos que usar `class` si queremos que el `template` compile:

```
template< template<class> class Container, class NestedType>
void func(const Container<NestedType> &value)
{
  // ...
}
```