# C++17 ¿Qué es? ¿No es C++?

Tags: c++, c++1z, c++17

Leyendo sobre el lenguaje C++ he visto que algunos desarrolladores hablan de C++17 y no me queda claro si es lo mismo que C++ o es otro lenguaje.

¿Qué es C++17?

Comment: Ya existe la etiqueta C++17... ¿no sería preferible esa etiqueta a [tag:C++1z]?

Comment: ¿Está el sinónimo hecho?

Comment: No. no existe el sinónimo

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### ¡C++17 es C++!.

Es la sexta revisión del Lenguaje de Programación C++, no se llama C++6 porque las revisiones no se numeran por el orden de revisión si no por el año en que la [Organización Internacional para la Estandarización (ISO)](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizaci%C3%B3n_Internacional_para_la_Estandarizaci%C3%B3n) dan el visto bueno a la revisión del lenguaje (también conocida como [Dialecto del Lenguaje de Programación](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect_(computing))).

#### ¿Qué hubo antes de C++17?

Este es un breve resumen de la historia del lenguaje C++:

- *1985*: Primera implementación comercial de C++.
- *1989*: Segunda versión de C++.
- *1998*: Primera ratificación ISO del lenguaje. Primer dialecto oficial de C++ conocido como **C++98**.
- *2003*: Segunda revisión del lenguaje, conocida como **C++03**.
- *2005*: Primera colección de documentos técnicos (Technical Report) conocida como TR1.
- *2007*: Se decide añadir las propuestas del TR1 al estándar, esta tercera revisión del lenguaje se conoce cmo **C++TR1**.
- *2011*: Cuarta revisión del lenguaje, conocida como **C++11**.
- *2014*: Quinta revisión del lenguaje, conocida como **C++14**.
- *2017*: Sexta revisión del lenguaje, conocida como **C++17**.

#### ¿Qué añade C++17?

Así pues, C++17 no es más que una revisión del lenguaje C++ ¿Qué añade esta revisión respecto a las versiones anteriores?

**Deducción de parámetros en objetos plantilla**.

Los objetos plantilla pueden deducir los parámetros de plantilla de forma parecida a cómo se deducen en las funciones plantilla:

```
template <typename T>
void funcion(T t) { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
struct objeto
{
    objeto(T t) : valor{t} {}
    T valor;
};

int main()
{
    funcion(0);   // Correcto, deduce int t
    funcion('Z'); // Correcto, deduce char t

    objeto o1(0);   // Correcto, deduce int valor. Antes de C++17 es error.
    objeto o2('Z'); // Correcto, deduce char valor. Antes de C++17 es error.

    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, esta deducción no funciona exactamente igual que la deducción de plantillas función, pues [no da soporte a deducción parcial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45747/deducci%c3%b3n-parcial-de-par%c3%a1metros-en-clase-plantilla-caracter%c3%adstica-c17).

**Deducción de tipos en parámetros plantilla no-tipo**.

Se puede usar `auto` como parámetro plantilla para que la plantilla deduzca el tipo subyacente del parámetro no-tipo facilitado:

```
//        vvvv <-- Antes de C++17 no se permite usar auto aqui.
template <auto T>
void funcion() { /* ... */ }

static int i = 0;

int main()
{
    funcion<0>();    // Correcto, T sera de tipo int con valor 0
    funcion<'Z'>();  // Correcto, T sera de tipo char con valor 'Z'
    funcion<&i>();   // Correcto, T sera de tipo int * con valor 0x????????

    funcion<3.14>(); /* Error, T deberia ser de tipo double,
    pero double y float no se permiten como parametro no-tipo */
    funcion<int>();  // Error, se esperaba un valor no un tipo.

    return 0;
}
```

**Permitir `typename` en plantillas-plantilla**.

Al declarar una plantilla-plantilla ahora se puede usar indistintamente `typename` o `class` ([antes no se podía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/540/son-iguales-class-y-typename-en-el-contexto-de-template/2528#2528)):

```
//      Correcto en C++17 y anterior --> vvvvv
template <typename T, template<typename> class P>
void funcion1(P<T>) { /* ... */ }
//   Correcto solo a partir de C++17 --> vvvvvvvv
template <typename T, template<typename> typename P>
void funcion2(P<T>) { /* ... */ }
```

**Expresiones plegables**.

Es posible aplicar ciertos operadores sobre paquetes de parámetros en plantillas variadicas:

```
template <typename ... args>
auto funcion(args ... a) { return (a + ...); }
//          Expresion plegada --> ^^^^^^^^^
int main()
{
    // Devuelve 21
    std::cout << funcion(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // Se despliega en return 1 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 6;
    // Devuelve hola mundo
    std::cout << funcion("hola"s, ' ', "mundo"s); // Se despliega en return "hola"s + ' ' + "mundo"s;

    return 0;
}
```

Los operadores plegables son: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `|`, `~`, `=`, `<`, `>`, `<<`, `>>`, `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `^=`, `&=`, `|=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=`, `&&`, `||`, `,`, `.*` y `->*` y pueden desplegarse así:

```
  ( expresion operador ... )
  ( ... operador expresion )
  ( expresion operador ... operador expresion )
```

**Nuevas normas de deducción para valores entre llaves (`{}`)**.

Cuando entre llaves sólo haya un valor se deducirá como valor, no como lista:

```
auto a{'a'}; // a es de tipo char, antes deducia std::initializer_list<char> de un elemento.
auto b{0xb}; // b es de tipo int, antes deducia std::initializer_list<int> de un elemento.
auto c{1.f}; // c es de tipo float, antes deducia std::initializer_list<float> de un elemento.
```

**Expandir paquetes de parámetros en cláusulas `using`**.

Teniendo un objeto base como el siguiente:

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    void f(T) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};
```

Y un objeto que deriva de varios `base`:

```
template <typename ... T>
struct derivado : base<T> ...
{
};
```

Podemos traer al ámbito de `derivado` todas las versiones de `base<T>::f(T)` con una cláusula using:

```
template <typename ... T>
struct derivado : base<T> ...
{
    using base<T>::f ...;
};

derivado<int, double, char> d;
/* Equivale a:
using base<int>::f;
using base<double>::f;
using base<char>::f; */
```

**Lambdas expresión constante**.

Si la lambda cumple los requisitos para ser una expresión constante, podrá usarse como tal:

```
// vvvvvvvvv <-- No se puede usar constexpr aqui antes de C++17
   constexpr auto cinco = [](){ return 5; };

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    switch (argc)
    {
//           vvvvvvv <-- Valido de C++17 en adelante
        case cinco(): /* ... */ break;
        default: std::cout << /* ... */ break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Podría omitirse `constexpr` en la declaración de la lambda pues serán expresiones constantes por defecto si cumplen con los requisitos para serlo.

**Capturar `*this` en lambdas**.

En una lambda declarada dentro de un método de un objeto, las capturas     genéricas capturan `this` como puntero:

```
struct objeto
{
    void f()
    {
//                v <-- Captura this por referencia
        auto a = [&]() { valor = 100 ; }; // Equivale a this->valor = 100;
//                v <-- Captura this por copia
        auto b = [=]() { valor = 200 ; }; // Equivale a this->valor = 200;
//                vvvvv <-- Copia el objeto
        auto c = [*this]() mutable { valor = 300 ; } // Equivale a this->valor = 300;

        a(); // this->valor contiene 100
        b(); // this->valor contiene 200
        c(); /* this->valor no se modifica, contiene 200.
                Se modifica el this->valor de una copia */
    }
    int valor;
};
```

**Atributo `[[fallthrough]]`**.

Indica al compilador que la ausencia de una instrucción `break` al final de un `case` en un `switch` es intencionada:

```
switch (variable)
{
    case 0:
        // Hacer cosas...
    case 1: // <-- ALarma! falta break!
        // Hacer cosas...
        [[fallthrough]];
    case 2: // <-- Ok, la falta de break es intencionada.
        // Hacer cosas...
        break;
}
```

**Atributo `[[nodiscard]]`**.

Indica al compilador que un tipo de dato o el retorno de una función no debe ser descartado.

```
//     vvvvvvvvvvvvv <-- Se aconseja no descartar este dato
struct [[nodiscard]] informacion { /* ... */ };
struct datos { /* ... */ };

informacion obtener_informacion() { /* ... */ }
   [[nodiscard]] datos obtener_datos() { /* ... */ }
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Se aconseja no descartar este retorno
int main()
{
    obtener_informacion(); // Alarma! Se esta descartando un objeto de tipo informacion!
    obtener_datos(); // Alarma! Se esta descartando el retorno de obtener_datos!
    return 0;
}
```

**Atributo `[[maybe_unused]]`**.

Indica al compilador que una entidad podría no estar siendo usada intencionadamente.

```
[[maybe_unused]] void debug() { std::cout << "Debug\n"; }

void f([[maybe_unused]] int valor)
{
    std::cout << "F!\n";
}
```

El código anterior no mostrará alarmas por no usar la función `debug` ni por no usar el valor `valor`.

**Atributos en espacios de nombres y enumerados**.

Es posible aplicar atributos sobre espacios de nombres y valores enumerados:

```
namespace [[deprecated]] utiles
{
void f() { /* ... */ }
}

enum puerto
{
    defecto = 8080,
    entrada = 8016,
    [[deprecated]] salida = 8015
};

void datos(puerto p) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    utiles::f(); // Alarma! el espacio de nombres f esta deprecado
    datos(defecto);
    datos(salida); // Alarma! puerto::salida esta deprecado
    return 0;
}
```

**Variables `inline`**.

Es posible hacer que las variables se comporten como funciones `inline`, esto es: considerar múltiples definiciones idénticas de la variable como la misma definición.

**Espacios de nombres anidados**.

El espacio de nombres:

```
namespace Primero
{
namespace Segundo
{
namespace Tercero
{
// Cosas...
}
}
}
```

Puede ser declarado como

```
namespace Primero::Segundo::Tercero
{
// Cosas...
}
```

**Simplificación de `static_assert`**.

Ya no es obligatorio añadir un texto a `static_assert`.

**Especificaciones de excepciones**.

A partir de C++17 si una función no dispone de cláusula `throw` en la firma se considera que no lanza excepciones.

**Emparejamiento estructurado**.

Para funciones con múltiples valores de retorno (Que devuelvan `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, `std::array` y agregados) es posible obtener cada valor de retorno por separado:

```
std::map<int, int> mii;
// i y b declarados por separado:
std::map<int, int>::iterator i;
bool b;
//       +---- Asigna el retorno->first a i y el retorno->second a b
//       |     Valido en C++17 y anterior.
//   vvvvvvvvv
std::tie(i, b) = mii.insert({1, 2});

/* iterador e insertado declarados en la misma línea, su tipo se deduce
de retorno->first y retorno->second respectivamente. Asigna el
retorno->first iterador y el retorno->second a insertado.
valido solo a partir de C++17 */
auto [iterador, insertado] = mii.insert({3, 4});
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Emparejamiento estructurado

struct abc { int a, b, c; };
abc f1() { return {2, 3, 5}; }
std::tuple<std::string, float, abc, int> f2() { return {"Hola mundo", 3.14f, {1, 2, 3}, 4}; }
std::array<int, 5> f3() { return {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; }

// Asigna retorno.a a x, retorno.b a y, retorno.c a z
auto [x, y, z] = f1();
//   ^^^^^^^^^ <--- Emparejamiento estructurado

// Asigna 1r elemento de la tupla a str, segundo a pi, tercero a xyz y cuarto a v
auto [str, pi, xyz, v] = f2();
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Emparejamiento estructurado

// Asigna retorno[0] a p0, retorno[1] a p1...
auto [p0, p1, p2, p3, p4] = f3();
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Emparejamiento estructurado
```

**Inicializador en estructuras de control**.

Es posible declarar e inicializar variables en `if` y `switch`:

```
if (auto [iterador, insertado] = mii.insert({3, 4}); !insertado)
    std::cout << "Elemento " << iterador->first << " repetido!\n";
else
    std::cout << "Elemento " << iterador->first << "anyadido con valor " << iterador->second << '\n';

switch (int i = f1() + f2(); i)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

**Bucle `for` de rango generalizado**.

Ahora se permite que `begin` y `end` en el for de rango sean de diferentes tipos.

**Condicion `if` constante**.

Se puede añadir `constexpr` a la cláusula `if`. Si la condición de la condición constante no se cumple el código dentro de dicha condición no se compilará.

```
#define DEBUG false

if constexpr (DEBUG)
{
    // Codigo que debe ser compilado solo en modo DEBUG
}
```

**WIP...**.

Añadiendo más cosas.